# Hiding menu item

Tags: routes

I have a "person" content type, and then I have a directory of people, which has a "Directory" menu item.

When I view John Doe's page, I would like "John Doe" menu item appear under "Directory", so that the menu looks like this:

```
> Directory
    - John Doe (selected)
```

**But** when I go to Directory page, I would *not* like John Doe to appear under it, so the menu looks like this:

```
> Directory (selected)
```

Is there any way to achieve it, preferably "native" Drupal way?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [Menu Position](https://drupal.org/project/menu_position) module and create a menu position rule specifying that all of your nodes of content-type "person" go under the Directory menu item.

Then you wont need to add all of your person nodes to the menu.

**OR**

You can edit you menu and disable all of the person menu items under Directory.